# Application Settings in IIS is empty, is that okay?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

In my IIS Manager panel. I double click Application Settings, but it is empty. That means there is no key and value. However the web site can be running without problem.

I am not sure does it matter? Or I have to manual to add some key/value pairs. My application is deployed by Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe... because it depends on the application.

The app can read these "Application Settings", for example the developper can check if an app setting called "EnableDebug" has the value "true" and enable additional logging, etc...

It's a feature available to the developer, some use it, some don't. The benefit is that you can change settings without having to rebuild the app.

So, you should ask the developper if you want to be sure.

Comment: In asp.net core, we put setting in `appsetting.json` file. So perhaps we don't need it?

Comment: That's another way to store app settings. If you use the IIS manager to add app settings, they will be stored in web.config

Comment: To be more specific, "Application Settings" in IIS Manager is strictly for ASP.NET and maps to `<appSetttings>` tag https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1